# Rerranging the integrand of an integral

Tags: integration, summation, gamma-function

Consider the integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda s}}{(1+is)^{1/2}}\,{\rm d}s$$

where $\lambda\to\infty$ is a positive scalar. My lecturer stated that the integral can be re-written in the form:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda s}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-is)^n\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}{n!\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}\,{\rm d}s$$

but I haven't ever met the Gamma function so I was wondering if someone could show me the manipulation in order to get it into this form.

---

By the binomial theorem we have that

$$(1+z)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{n}z^n$$

using this we find

$$(1+is)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{n}(is)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1/2)(-3/2)\cdots(-1/2-n+1)}{n!}(is)^n$$

How do I proceed? Also, his solution has $(-is)^n$ whereas mine is only $(is)^n$. How do you fix this?

Comment: This is just the taylor series of $1/(1+is)^{0.5}$ (aka Binomial Series) and products are replaced by the Gamma function. Btw I am not sure if your teacher said something about convergence, but this is definitly not converging for every $s$. Hence, you need to split the integral into two parts.

Comment: @MrYouMath I have modified this using the binomial theorem but I have no idea where the Gamma's come in! In fact $\lambda\to\infty$, does that change the convergence?

Comment: Hmm ... If you apply $\lambda \to \infty$ after integration the convergence is still problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply an application of the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) to $(1+is)^{-1/2}$, which states that $$(1+z)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} z^k,$$ where $$\binom{\alpha}{k} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots (\alpha-k+1)}{k!}$$ for non-integer $\alpha$.  Then observe that $\Gamma(n+1/2)/\Gamma(1/2)$ is simply $(n-1/2)(n-3/2)\cdots(1/2)$.

Comment: Just look up the definition of the Gamma function. Heropup has explained it in the last line.